# Light Fall co-ordinates in babylonjs

Tags: javascript, math, coordinates, light, babylonjs

I have been working on the lights in Babylon.js ,The problem is to find the co-ordinates of the light fall in the ground.The known parts are angle,position(x,y,z) and direction (x,y,z) of the light,basically the center of the ground is (0,0,0).Need to find the co-ordinates of the light fall from the center of the ground in(x,z) in javascript,or any math calculation or even in Babylon.js

The problem is to find the co-ordinates of the light fall in the ground.

Comment: Need to find array of co-ordinates inorder to map the light fall which may be in any form of circular shape